# ngSelect select all values by default

Tags: html, angular, typescript, angular-ngselect

I programmed a filter in Angular. As default I would like to select all options. At the moment my HTML looks like that

```
<ng-select [items]="categoryFolders"
           [multiple]="true"
           bindLabel="folderId"
           bindValue="folderId"
           placeholder="Filter..."
           [closeOnSelect]=false
           [(ngModel)]="selectedItem"
           (ngModelChange)="changedSelectedItems(selectedItem)">
</ng-select>
```

if I set the selectedItem value inside the typescript to categoryFolders. It gives me an error:

*ng-select-ng-select.mjs:1942 Setting object({"folderId":"xxx"}) as your model with bindValue is not allowed unless [compareWith] is used.*

where do I have to use the [compareWith] keyword? Do i have to do something else?

My items only have 1 value and that is a string, that serves as id and value.

If this is a repost, please point me to the original.

Comment: Make a functional example for us in stackblitz.

Comment: Add the definition of `changedSelectedItems` please, also include the initial `selectedItem`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ng-select-xamdpn?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

I shortened it a little bit, but essentially it should be the same

Comment: @Janick.Spielmann That stackblitz doesn't show an error for me

Comment: Yeah it works just fine, but if you open it not everything is selected...
So if I open the SB I want to see all selected.